# WPF MVVM: View is not reloaded when ViewModel is changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate

I have a WPF application based on the MVVM pattern. It has a tree on the left side and a details area on the right side. The tree contains objects of various types and I have a view model for each type. In the view, I have a different data template (containing a user control) for each view model type. The view is then selected via databinding based on the current details view.

Now, when I switch between tree nodes, I also instantiate a new details view model for each node and the view gets changed accordingly, firing both the DataContextChanged event and the Loaded event. That is, until I start to switch between objects of the same type. Here, too, the details view model gets updated, but the view instance stays the same. This means, only the DataContextChanged event is fired, but not the Loaded event.

Is there a way to force the Loaded event to fire, for instance, by re-initializing the view?

The reason why I need the Loaded event is that WPF fires the selection change events on input controls during data binding and since I have logic that acts upon user-triggered selection change events, I need to be able to ignore those triggered by data binding. For now, the Loaded event seems to be the best option to do this. Escept for the described issue.

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Sounds like a bad design to me if you need any SelectionChanged events at all, you should be able to bind the details view directly to the selected item instead. Especially the fact that you need different behaviour for binding selection changes sounds rather fishy. Besides that it would be helpful if you were to post some simplified code of your problem.

Comment: Please, post your code that reproduces mentioned problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I can see now that a sample application will highlight this better. Unfortunately (for me) it will be a couple of days before I can put one together. Oh, and how can I attach a file containing the sample?

Comment: You cannot attach it here. You can however post it to code.google.com / codeplex.com by creating a new project like Micheal's code samples and link it here.

Answer (score 0):

Move whatever logic you have in the Loaded handler to the DataContextChanged handler if it needs to run every time the data context changes.

Comment: Am sorry, but I already tried that. The Loaded-event *does not* fire when the type of the view does not change.

Comment: To clarify: The Loaded event for a view is fired when the view is loaded (changes as you call it). The Loaded event is not fired when the data context changes. The DataContextChanged event is fired when the data context changes. If you want something done abery time the data context changes, put that logic in the event handler for DataContextChanged.

Comment: I understand that. The problem is, that WPF itself decides that it does not have to reload the view when the view model instance changes unless the instance is of a different type, thus requiring a different view. It is very likely that this is by design in WPF. Nonetheless, it removes the Loaded event from the list of possible hooks that fire *after* the selection change event that fires because of the change of the data context.